# Upgrade to grails 2.3.5 : validator exception

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Since the upgrade to grails 2.3.5, a strange behaviour of the hibernate plugin (moved from version 3.6.10.6  to 3.6.10.7) results in a bean error at runtime:

```
14-01-22 16:22:54,064 ERROR [GrailsContextLoader] - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'xxx.xxxx.StatisticsValidator': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.setProxyHandler(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.proxy.ProxyHandler); nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.determineCommonAncestor(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.xxx.xxxx.StatisticsValidator': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.setProxyHandler(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.proxy.ProxyHandler); nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.determineCommonAncestor(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.setProxyHandler(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.proxy.ProxyHandler); nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.determineCommonAncestor(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
```

Here is the `Statistics` domain class which is concerned, even if nothing has been changed since grails 2.3.4:

```
class Statistics implements Serializable {

    static belongsTo = [profile: Profile]

    Profile profile

    String email
    String dbkey
    String clientCode
    String affiliatesNbr
    String freeStorageBonus
    String freeUsersBonus
    String storageUsed
    String storageAvailable
    String quotaUsersCurrent
    String quotaUsersAvailable
    String comments

    Date processedDate


    static constraints = {
        profile unique: true, nullable: false, blank: false
        email email: true, maxSize: 80, nullable: false, blank: false
        dbkey maxSize: 80, nullable: false, blank: false
        clientCode maxSize: 40, nullable: false, blank: false
        affiliatesNbr maxSize: 40, nullable: true, blank: true
        freeStorageBonus maxSize: 40, nullable: true, blank: true
        freeUsersBonus maxSize: 40, nullable: true, blank: true
        storageUsed maxSize: 40, nullable: true, blank: true
        storageAvailable maxSize: 40, nullable: true, blank: true
        quotaUsersCurrent maxSize: 40, nullable: true, blank: true
        quotaUsersAvailable maxSize: 40, nullable: true, blank: true
        comments maxSize: 180, nullable: true, blank: true
        processedDate nullable: true, blank: true
    }
```

Below the list of plugins used:

```
  plugins {
        build   ":tomcat:7.0.50"
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.7" 
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3" //jquery:1.10.2
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
        compile ":cache:1.1.1"
        compile ":bean-fields:1.0"
        compile ":csv:0.3.1"
        compile ":famfamfam:1.0.1"
        compile ":form-helper:0.2.8"
        compile ":google-chart:0.5.2"
        compile ":google-visualization:0.6.2"
        compile ":jcaptcha:1.2.1"
        compile ":jdbc-pool:7.0.47"
        compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
        compile ":navigation:1.3.2"
        compile ":quartz:1.0.1" //1.0.1
        compile ":richui:0.8"
        compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
        compile ":webflow:2.0.8.1"
        compile ":rendering:0.4.4"
        compile ":modernizr:2.7.1.1"
        compile ":spring-security-acl:2.0-RC1"
        compile ":pdf-viewer:0.1"
        compile ":taggable:1.0.1"
        compile ":executor:0.3"
        compile ":gmetrics:0.3.1"
        compile ":lesscss-resources:1.3.3"
        compile ":pretty-size:0.2"
        compile ":mysql-connectorj:5.1.22.1"
        compile ":font-awesome-resources:4.0.3.0"
        compile ":aws-sdk:1.6.12" 
        compile ":aws:1.6.7.5"
    }
```

Comment: Seems like a jar conflict - please update the question with the plugins you're using - you might want to copy/paste the whole plugins block from BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: list of plugins added, sounds weird as a gorm error, looks like a conflict with hibernate last update..